# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Has anyone ever ran into an error like this?

> Boomerang:527 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://rh--dev03--c.visualforce.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at Object.sendBeacon (https://rh--dev03--c.visualforce.com/resource/1544235289000/Boomerang:527:44)

This is my code

I thought I was catching all errors, I've been stuck for a while. I am not understanding this error.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="MTX_MatrixDetailViewController" cache="true">
    <style>
        body{
        margin: 0px !important;
        }
        .spinner{
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        height: 2em;
        width: 2em;
        overflow: show;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        }
    </style>


    <apex:includeLightning />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.plannerEditedActivityAPI)}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.plannerSettingsAPI)}" />

    <c:MTX_MatrixConsoleAPI />
    <c:BoomerangJs />


    <div id="matrix" />


    <script>

    var labelObject = {};
    labelObject.Missing_Required_Field = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Missing_Required_Field)}';
    labelObject.Due_Date = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Due_Date)}';
    labelObject.Category = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Category)}';
    labelObject.Type = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Type)}';
    labelObject.Priority = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Priority)}';
    labelObject.Assigned_To = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Assigned_To)}';
    labelObject.Frequency_Required_For_Recurring = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Frequency_Required_For_Recurring)}';
    labelObject.Next_Date_Required_For_Recurring = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Next_Date_Required_For_Recurring)}';
    labelObject.Next_Date_must_be_greater_than_previous_activity_s_date = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Next_Date_must_be_greater_than_previous_activity_s_date)}';
    labelObject.ActivityUI_Invalid_Time_Message = '{!JSENCODE($Label.ActivityUI_Invalid_Time_Message)}';
    labelObject.Last_Temp_Order = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.Account.fields.Last_Temp_Order_Date__c.Label)}';
    labelObject.Last_Perm_Order = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.Account.fields.Last_Perm_Order_Date__c.Label)}';
    labelObject.Primary = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.MP_Phone__c.fields.Primary__c.Label)}';
    labelObject.Preferred_Mobile = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.MP_Phone__c.fields.Preferred_Mobile__c.Label)}';
    labelObject.Phone_Type = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.MP_Phone__c.fields.Type__c.Label)}';
    labelObject.PermStatus = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.Contact.fields.Perm_Status__c.Label)}';
    labelObject.TempStatus = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.Contact.fields.Temp_Status__c.Label)}';
    labelObject.PersonalEmail = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.Contact.fields.Personal_Email__c.Label)}';
    labelObject.InvalidValue = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Invalid_Value)}';
    labelObject.NextDateRequired = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Next_Date_is_required)}';
    labelObject.Candidate = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Candidate)}'
    labelObject.Contact = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Contact)}';
    labelObject.JobOrder = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.Job_Order__c.Label)}';
    labelObject.Company = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.Account.Label)}';
    labelObject.Branch = '{!JSENCODE($ObjectType.Branch__c.Label)}';
    labelObject.LOB = '{!JSENCODE($Label.LOB)}';    
    labelObject.Owner = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Owner)}';


    window.plannerSettingsAPI.setLabels(labelObject);

    $Lightning.use("c:MTX_MatrixApp", function() {


        $Lightning.createComponent("c:MTX_MatrixDetailView",
                                   {
                                       "candidateId" : "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}",
                                       "service": window.plannerEditedActivityAPI,
                                       "settingsService": window.plannerSettingsAPI,
                                       "queriedActivities" : JSON.parse('{!jsEncode(activities)}')                                             
                                   },
                                   "matrix",
                                   function(cmp) {

                                   });
    });
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is a CORS error, nothing to do with Apex at all. We would need to see the relevant Visualforce code.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized i put up my .cmp code and not vf, I changed it @sfdcfox